# What do I put on php.ini for Zend Installation?

Tags: zend-framework

I have saved Zend to a folder on my hosting called `httpdocs`.  From what I've read on other questions, I understand I'm now supposed to add something to the php.ini file, and I know it's supposed to look something like the line below.  Is the `.;c:` standard or would it be different depending on my server?  If so, how do I determine what I should have instead?

```
include_dir = .;c:\httpdocs\ZendGdata-1.11.2\library
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

you are probably referring to the include path, which should be set so zend classes can be correctly loaded.

however i take the guess you are on an shared hosting enviornment where you cant do that.
you can. well you probably could it in htaccess but its unlikely.

you can however do this at runtime using the [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) functions

be sure not to loose your old include paths, specially "." which refers to the current directory.

however this is very well explained at zend framework manuals, please red the [introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.html)

and also try to improve your accept rate.

Comment: answers you accept devided by questions with no accepted answers but legit answers. but thats a question for meta.stackoverflow.com or the FAQ. so you could change php.ini but you dont have to. it would make sense if you had multiple websites all utilising the zend library and you wouldnt want to set the include path in all the applications.

Comment: are you saying that Zend should work as-is, without any change to the php.ini file?

Comment: thats correct. php.ini settings are optional. u usually need either the zend loader loaded correctly or the include paths set up and then includedthe required classes directly. or both if you want everything to be automatically. but it doesnt matter where you set your include path. its absolutely possible at runtime and probably even better if you have your zend library within the application so the paths stay correct.

Comment: Wow, first thing I do is eliminate `.` from the include path. A lean include path is an efficient one.